# pg_dump is available in AgensGraph?

Tags: pg-dump, agens-graph

I know the function "pg_dump" for backup and restore. 
But I never tried because so scared. 
Question is simple. Can I use that function for graph data? 
Or Is the other function supported for that? There's no information in their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer the [postgreSQL pg_dump document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pgdump.html) coz nothing different from doing bakcup on postgreSQL.

I referred the guide to create dump script with crontab and both dump and restore worked fine.

In my case, I used pg_dump for creating dump file and restore it with psql. You may choose pg_restore instead if necessary.

```
agens@karl ~] pg_dump --port=5432 --username=agens --file=agens.dump agens
agens@karl ~] psql --port=5432 --username=agens --dbname=agens2 -f agens.dump
```

However, I no longer use pg_dump for backup task due to the incremental bakcup requirement. So I googled available backup OSS for postgresql. Among the options I searched, [pg_rman](http://ossc-db.github.io/pg_rman/) is currently what I am using.

It made me easier to build a scheduling script for archive backup every 6 hours, incremental backup every day and full backup every week and those jobs are working properly more than 2 months so far.

Restoring the data on other severs is tested successfully as well.

Hope this helpful for you.